# SharePoint server 2013 central administration become unavailable after installing active directory

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, active-directory

I have SharePoint 2013 installed inside windows server 2008 r2 and it was working fine, but after I install Active directory on the windows server I try to aces the SharePoint central administrator but it gave me the following error:-

**Service Unavailable
HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.**

So how I can fix this issue?
BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this isn't production, it's not a supported practice to install AD on a SharePoint server. However, the error message you're receiving should be as simple as required services not running. Check Services and IIS and make sure everything is running. You might not be able to run them since they might be using accounts that no longer exist. When you install AD, local accounts are deactivated and converted to AD accounts. You may need to reconfigure services and application pools.

Better yet, revert back to a previous state of the server (if you have the backup) and install AD elsewhere.

HTH

Comment: i see , but this is a development server and i need to have active directory on the same server as sharepoint, to test the integration between sharepoint and active directory. so in this case i should re-configure the IIS and SP to use the new users ?

Comment: Oh good, I was hoping it was dev ;). Then yes, go through Services first, see what's not running and try to start. Then hit IIS, check app pools, change identities accordingly. You'll also need to tell SP about the new accounts specifically for the farm and central admin. This should help in that area: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2010/01/08/changing-sharepoint-2010-service-accounts.aspx

Comment: thanks for the link , but it is saying as i first step i need to access the Central Administrator. which in my case is no longer accessable. any adivce?

Comment: Duh, sorry about that. Search for some PowerShell commands, they're out there. If you can do it in CA, you can do it in PS.